# iOS7 itms-services scheme not work?

Tags: ios, ios7, iphone-web-app, in-house-distribution

I have an in-house app which I distribute over a local wifi

in release page have a link like this

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://192.168.1.231/app/plist/houseApp/out.plist
```

this worked on iOS 7 Safari

but when i add this page to main screen (like web app)

the same link didn't work, and apache access.log have no record about /app/plist/houseApp/out.plist

this worked in iOS 6

Anybody knows about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Apple have disabled all URL schemas in iOS7 (including mailto: links) in standalone webapps. This has seriously implications for my place of work.

See this post: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5385948?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 14):

On the 7.1 update all software installation services are forced to use the HTTPS protocol, also covering non-standard itms-services:// URLs.

You need to change the protocol type:

- from: itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://yourdomain.com/manifest.plist
- to: itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://yourdomain.com/manifest.plist

For more detail and how to get a certificate go to: [Fix certificate error on iOS 7](http://cases.azoft.com/how-to-fix-certificate-is-not-valid-error-on-ios-7/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in iOS 8.0. Simply use `https` for URLs.

[image: Screenshot for answer]