# itms-services protocol not detected as link - iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8

In iOS 7 when I added:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=
```

to an HTML page,  the Safari web browser on iOS would detect this as a link. Users could click it to download the app.

In iOS 8 the itms-services protocal doesn't seem to be detected as a link. Users now have to copy and paste it into the Safari address bar.

Am I missing something? Is this a bug? Additional security ?

Message was edited by markdn on 10/1/14 at 11:56 AM

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct `itms-services` syntax:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=yourURL
```

I don't know where you got the semicolon from in what you pasted, but that was probably messing you up.

On a related note, you may want to use the `href` HTML attribute to make a link:

```html
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=yourURL">Click Here To Install</a>
```

On a side note, [URL schemas are disabled in standalone web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19182967/2446155)

Comment: I updated my description fixing the semicolon - must of copied that incorrectly

Is this a markdown / github formatting thing possibly?

This is a gist I created to try to get the links to work:
https://gist.github.com/mrkd/69af52f6db9c31119e51

Comment: @MarkNorgren Yeah, looks like a markdown thing. It adds all sorts of complications beyond a simple `href`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use correct HTML to generate a clickable link. I just tried and an a-Tag still works on iOS 8 to download Apps.